# Meteor stylus import

Tags: import, meteor, stylus

I'm working on meteor site design, built with meteor. I'm using stylus to write the css. I've read that Meteor supports stylus import by default, but when I split my main stylesheet in partials, they get imported separatly by meteor. If I want to comment out a partial to disable it it still get's imported.

I have the following structure:

```
site/
  client/
    stylesheets/
      partials/
        all.styl
        typography.styl
        webform.styl
        etc.styl
      main.styl
```

In main.styl I do `@import 'partials/all` and all imports all of the partials:

```
@import 'typography'
@import 'webform'
@import 'etc'
```

Are `@import` in stylus supported by meteor? I've tried to add the stylus package, stylus-latest but to no avail.

This people seem to says that it works out of the box: https://github.com/percolatestudio/ground-control. I tried to run the app but it doesn't work with meteor latest.

Anybody haz tip?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.import.styl` for files you will import. 
It was fixed in https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1803

Answer (score 2):

This is a complicated issue. `@imports` work for other stylus plugins such as `nib`, because each file runs its own set of plugins. However, for imports across a project, the regular way won't work because Meteor will load each file. This is discussed in the following thread:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/462

The workarounds are to import the file manually, either by

- Put some files to manually import in a `.import` directory (or anything that starts with `.`, which is ignored by Meteor)
- Put change the extension of the file to something `.stylimport` which is also ignored by Meteor.

Both of the issues above have the problem that Meteor won't watch the file for changes during development. If you'd like this issue fixed, I'd encourage you to pitch in on that discussion.

Comment: This said, in the meantime i will switch to less with .lessimport. That let Meteor do the compiling. I've tried .stylimport but stylus complains when I try to import a file with `@import 'file.stylimport'`

Comment: I guess they are working on it. Stylus import work fine from the root of the folder but not from client/ or nested folder.

Comment: Ok so it actually work. I moved my main.styl out of the `client/stylesheets/` folder and I `@import 'client/stylesheets/file`. I dont know if it can be an issue, but it's all good for me now. Plus, i don't have to use less :)

Comment: further clarification: main.styl `@import 'client/stylesheets/all'`. all.styl `@import 'file-1'`, `@import 'file-2'`, etc...

Comment: @YannickSchall are you sure that this isn't resulting in duplication of your CSS on the client side? (Are you using `.lessimport` extension?) What about hot code reload, does it detect when you change an imported file?

Comment: Actually you are right, I was mistaken. I checked the output and all of the stylus files are loaded individually, which is a bummer. I worked on a previous project with `.lessimport` and it seemed fine. I will have to give up on stylus then :(

Comment: I've decide to put all of my `.styl` files in `stylesheets/.include/` folder. I then run stylus watch as a separate process and output one css file in the `stylesheets/` folder. This way, meteor ignores all `@import` and reload the css automatically everytime. `stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus -w .includes/main.styl -o ./`

Comment: @YannickSchall you should write all these comments in an answer so that someone else can piece them together when they also have this question.

Answer (score 1):

My previous attempt to use `@import` with meteor-stylus was ill fated.

I tried to leave the `main.styl` at the root of the application and load the imports from `/client/stylesheets`. I thought it worked, but as mentionned by @AndrewMao it duplicates the code.

I worked on a previous project with less and `.lessimport` extension. but for this one I want to keep using stylus. So I decided to move **all** of my `.styl` in `client/stylesheets/.includes/`. I run `stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus -w .includes/main.styl -o ./` to output a fresh copy of the css each time the stylus watcher compiles the files. This way it keep the benefits of meteor hot reload.

I wish there was a way to specify the option for the stylus-autoprefixer cli. anybody knows if it's possible? otherwise i'll have to use [prepos app](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/).

Comment: All of this might be coming to meteor soon, https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor/commit/31400f3fef79807724f839ce07e2ab2596dd5c17 and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1803

Comment: Clever to import a hidden file like that.